# The difference between GCM and PARSE push messages

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I am buiding an android app which will be receiving notifications from my server. This means all my users which is above 1 million, will receive notifications from my server. I know parse and google cloud messaging(GCM) can do the push messages but please I want to know the best out of this two (parse and GCM) so I can implement it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you any idea about how to migrate parse installation data to GCM Server Application (which is create by us PHP)?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications you can see:

`The Parse library provides push notifications by using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).`

So you have to register your app to GCM console to send push notification in anyway.

**When to NOT use parse.com?**

If you already have a backend service, you can easily implement push notification since there are plenty of third part libraries for different platforms such as node.js, php etc.

**When to use parse.com?**

If you don't have backend-service and you just want to send push notifications also if you don't want to spend your time by setting up server stuff then you can go with parse.com

**NOTE:** Facebook shuts down parse by January 2017 so please consider it.(http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/)

Comment: Have you any idea about how to migrate parse installation data to GCM Server Application (which is create by us PHP)?

Answer (score 1):

`Android push notification` is a service used to send messages directly to the Android Mobile Devices.

There are several ways we can implement Android push notification.

1. Google Cloud Messaging(GCM)
2. Parse Notification(Parse.com)

You are asking which one is the best way to implement :

The standard way is using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) but there are some alternatives like Parse Notification,Which is easier to use.

If you need to handle Json Push messages,Refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/)

**Steps involved in send Push notifications:**

Developing the application involves `two` parts:

**GCM Server Application** – Create Web application using Php to send message to User via GCM Cloud server

**GCM Client Application** – Create Android application which receive message sent from GCM Server Web App

For More Informations regarding to [GCM server and Client Application](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-gcm-service/)

Comment: Have you any idea about how to migrate parse installation data to GCM Server Application (which is create by us PHP)?

Comment: @milapTank I don't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Parse uses GCM and uses own service for Kindle

Answer (score 0):

Please Go with google cloud messaging(GCM) .It is very easy to integrate in android app. the problem with parse in some case device token or registration id is not register at their database so User of parse does not get push notification.In case of GCM we can sure for device token

So my recommendation is GCM 
Hope this will help you.